# invoking private methods using property notation

Tags: groovy

The code sample below indicates that you can call private methods using property notation, e.g. `val` instead of `getVal()`, and presumably `val = "something"` instead of `setVal("something")`

```
class Foo {

  String foo = val    
  private getVal() { "val"}
}

assert new Foo().foo == "val"
```

I'm aware that this style is "officially supported" for public methods, but is it's use for private methods a bug/quirk, which one should rely on (much like the ability to access private members from outside a class)?

Answer (score 0):

I've probably got the wrong end of the stick, but doesn't the same thing happen in Java...

Can't see how that differs from having:

```
class PrivateTest {
  public String foo = getVal() ;

  private String getVal() {
    return "val" ;
  }
}
```

and then the test class:

```
public class PrivateMain {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    PrivateTest pt = new PrivateTest() ;
    System.out.println( pt.foo ) ;
  }
}
```

The test class will still print out `val`

Comment: My point is that from inside a class you can invoke a private method `getX()` using just `X`, but the docs/books I've read only mention using this property syntax for public methods. What I want to know is whether it's OK to use this for private methods too? Just because it works, doesn't necessarily mean it's OK.

Comment: @Don Does groovy currently even have a concept of private?  I think it will just try to call `getX` if it exists, no matter what its access level

Comment: Groovy definitely has a concept of private, but the current implementation is buggy http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3010

Answer (score 0):

now that you mention it...
i don't remember how private members are handled.

but at least in the 1.8 instance i have running (no security manager in place), you can do things like

```
println new Date().fastTime
println new Date().normalize()
```

-- edit
i should really pay more attention
in your example, new Foo().foo is just accessing a standard groovy property.
`new Foo().val` or `new Foo().getVal()` on the other hand, would actually access the private members.

-- edit 2
wow. i truly didn't remember [GROOVY-3010](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3010)